# Como desabilitar Migrations de um projeto com EF6?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, code-first, entity-framework-6

Olá!

Tenho uma class library com modelos usando Code First e habilitei Migrations com o comando "enable-migrations" no PMC para testar e funciona muito bem. Como estou no inicio das definições de models, prefiro deixar isso para depois que fizer o primeiro deploy de produção.

Como desabilito o Migrations do meu projeto?

Answer (score 3):

Coloque `false` no `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` e quando precisar novamente coloque `true`.

**Exemplo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<YourContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Também pode se usar `Add-Migration InitialSchema -IgnoreChanges`, para criar uma migration vazia sob o modelo atual.

Nesse [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/dn579398), tem videos e explicações interessantes sobre o assunto, apesar de estar em inglês, o texto está muito fácil o entendimento.

*Referências*

- [Code First Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)
- [Code First Migrations and Deployment with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)