# HasColumnName não reconhece campo

Tags: entity-framework-6

Estou trabalhando com o Entity Framework 6.1, utilizando a abordagem **code first**. Mapeio a minha classe no banco de dados através da classe `EntityTypeConfiguration`.

Quando faço o mapeamento de uma propriedade com um campo da tabela, utilizando o código abaixo, por exemplo:

```
namespace Dominio
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    public class UF
    {
        private int iduf;
        private string nome;
        private string sigla;

        public  int IdUf
        {
            get { return this.iduf; }
            set { this.iduf = value; }
        }

        public  string Nome
        {
            get { return this.nome; }
            set { this.nome = value; }
        }

        public  string Sigla
        {
            get { return this.sigla; }
            set { this.sigla = value; }
        }

    }
}



namespace DAO
{
    class UFConfig:EntityTypeConfiguration<UF>
    {
        public UFConfig()
        {


            this.HasKey(u => u.IdUf);
            this.Property(u =>u.IdUf).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            this.Property(u => u.Sigla);
            this.Property(u => u.Nome);

            this.ToTable("uf");
            this.Property(u => u.IdUf).HasColumnName("IDUF") ;
            this.Property(u => u.Sigla).HasColumnName("SIGLA");
            this.Property(u => u.Nome).HasColumnName("nome_UF");


        }
    }
}
```

Tabela no Banco

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[uf](
    [iduf] [int] NOT NULL,
    [sigla] [varchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [nome_uf] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_uf] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [iduf] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Como retorno, tenho o seguinte:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'DAO.UF'. A member of the type, 'Nome', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

**Pergunto:** eu tenho que obrigatoriamente utilizar o padrão do Entity Framework para nomear as colunas da minha tabela do banco de dados?

Comment: precisamos da `DAO.UF` e precisamos que você coloque todo o `mapeamento` (EntityTypeConfiguration) na sua totalidade, porque o HasColumnName reconhece isso sim!!!

Comment: quando eu modifico o campo na tabela para nome, ele funciona normalmente. O problema é que eu possuo as classes em um padrão e o banco em outro, seria muito trabalhoso se eu tivesse de colocar o meu banco no padrão do entity framework, assim como o inverso também ficaria ruim.

Comment: Eu não disse diferente, o que eu quero que você edite a questão e coloque todo o código corresponde a sua pergunta, entendeu @dhielyton

Comment: ok, entendi, ja fiz a edição. @FCCDias

Comment: Você poderia postar o esquema da tabela no banco de dados?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque:

```
class UFConfig:EntityTypeConfiguration<UF>
{
    public UFConfig()
    {
        this.ToTable("uf");
        this.HasKey(u => u.IdUf).HasColumnName("IDUF").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);        
        this.Property(u => u.Sigla).HasColumnName("SIGLA");
        this.Property(u => u.Nome).HasColumnName("nome_UF");
    }
}
```

Use o comando logo abaixo no PM ([Package Manage Consoler](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console)):

```
Add-Migration InitialSchema -IgnoreChanges
```

No seu caso caso habilite esse item no Configuration.cs

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<YourContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Depois utilize um

```
Update-Database
```

---

*Como você escolheu `CodeFirst`, vai ser obrigado a utilizar [Migrations](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) para ajustes e alterações*

*Referência:*

- [Como desabilitar Migrations de um projeto com EF6?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13554/como-desabilitar-migrations-de-um-projeto-com-ef6/13557#13557)
- [Code First Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)
- [Code First Migrations and Deployment with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)
- [Finding and Installing a NuGet Package Using the Package Manager Console](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console)

Comment: fiz, o que vc me orientou, continuou o mesmo problema. @FCCDias

Comment: O banco já existe?

Comment: sim, o banco já existe. @FCCDias

Comment: Editei o post ... como você tinha uma base pronta e começou a desenvolver por code first faça esses comandos

Comment: funcionou, valew @FCCDias, obrigado.